# What is reason for '?.' in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular8

I saw the following syntax in the HTML template of an Angular app, and I'm wondering what it does.

`<label>{{header?.title}}</label>`

Can anyone tell me the reason for `?.`, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you get response data from a HTTP call in a TS file, it is asynchronous. Also, the HTML DOM loads before that response. So, to ensure it will not show an error like

> 'header' or 'title' is undefined

type `{{header?.title}}` rather than `{{header.title}}`.

Answer (score 7):

It is a way of avoiding null exception.It says if header has a title then show the value.

Answer (score 2):

This is a kind of **short hand for ternary condition**.

It will bind the property `title` only if `header` object is valid.

For example, Typical way of writing ternary condition is,

```
{{header ? header.title : ""}}
```

Can be written as

```
{{header?.title}}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's called **Safe Navigation Operator** which can be used to prevent Angular from throwing errors, when trying to access object properties of an object that don’t exist.

E.g.       `{{header?.title}}`

Here it is, protecting against a view render failure if the `header` is null. This will evaluate name only if an `header` is not null or undefined. This comes in handy when an `header` is something that is loaded asynchronously.

It usually helps in scenarios where data is coming from HTTP Service.